# Enough permitions to login a created user

Tags: sql, sql-server

Every time I'm launching SQL server I run a script that destroys my little local database, refills it with example data, destroys some logins that were artificially created using this script.

```
exec sp_addlogin  @loginame = 'strong',  @passwd ='strong',  @defdb =KornDurnDB_new;
exec sp_adduser   @loginame = 'strong',   @name_in_db = 'strng';
```

To this login I give **ALL** grants(according to ANSI-92 standart), but It is not enough to authorize using this login, when sql management studio launches.  Sql management studio returns me error 18456.

What can a add to make a login with that account and password?

**UPDATED(SOLUTION):**  I have just reinstalled MS SQL server with other installaton properties and its working

Comment: `@name_in_db = 'strng';` <-- should this be **strong** also

Comment: Am I allowed to  write strng, not strong or it will bring an error?

Comment: should be a state= with that error message, it's state that tells you what's actually wrong

Comment: State 1 is just a masque state.  Which state do the SQL Server Error Logs show?

Comment: @Andomar, I have just reinstalled MS SQL server with other installaton properties and its working

Answer (score 2):

You might be creating a user in the `master` database instead of the `KornDurnDB_new` database.  Try:

```
exec sp_addlogin  @loginame = 'strong',  @passwd = 'strong',  @defdb = KornDurnDB_new;
use KornDurnDB_new;
exec sp_adduser   @loginame = 'strong',   @name_in_db = 'strng';
```

Note that both [`sp_addlogin`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173768.aspx) and [`sp_adduser`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181422.aspx) are obsolete.  Their replacements are [`create login`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) and [`create user`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx).